# Folder Structure for App Engine using PHP to Set Up the Drive API

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-drive-api, require

The Google documentation example for setting up the Google Drive API to work with PHP, has require statements like this:

```
<?php
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/Google_Client.php';
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_DriveService.php';

other code
?>
```

I downloaded a .zip file from GitHub, and extracted it.  In the extracted folders and files, the google-api-php-client files from GitHub, do **not** contain a file named ***Google_Client.php***.  There is a file named, ***Client.php*** in the ***src/Google/*** directory.

And there is no ***contrib*** folder either.

***AND***, there is no file named ***DriveService.php*** in the download of the GitHub google-api-php-client files.

So, I'm assuming that the references to the files and folders should look like this:

```
<?php
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/Google/Client.php';
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/Google/Drive.php';

other code
?>
```

The ***Client.php*** file contains a `require_once` statement, for an autoload.php file:

```
if (!class_exists('Google_Client')) {
  require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/../autoload.php';
}
```

The double dots in the reference `/../` indicates that when the file ***autoload.php*** is being searched for in order to include, go up to the parent folder, and search there.

So the folder structure should be:

```
src - Folder
  autoload.php

  Google - Folder  
    Client.php
    DriveService.php
```

The autoload.php file code is:

```
<?php

function google_api_php_client_autoload($className)
{
  $classPath = explode('_', $className);
  if ($classPath[0] != 'Google') {
    return;
  }
  // Drop 'Google', and maximum class file path depth in this project is 3.
  $classPath = array_slice($classPath, 1, 2);

  $filePath = dirname(__FILE__) . '/' . implode('/', $classPath) . '.php';
  if (file_exists($filePath)) {
    require_once($filePath);
  }
}

spl_autoload_register('google_api_php_client_autoload');
```

The ***Drive.php*** file has no `require` or `include` statements in it.

There is also a **Service** folder in the downloaded files, and there is a ***Service.php*** file in the Google folder.

Is the documentation wrong, and my suggestion right?  What is the correct set up for the Drive API in PHP?

Answer (score 1):

The folder structure from the zip file from GitHub is different than the folder structure of files and folders obtained from Subversion.  When the Google API PHP Client Library is downloaded with Subversion, there is a ***contrib*** folder, and there are files named ***Google_Client.php*** and ***Google_DriveService.php***.  I had downloaded and extracted files from GitHub from a zip file.  That creates a very different outcome then downloading the files with Subversion.  Subversion renames the files I guess, and creates different folder names.  So, with the new download of folders and files using Subversion, the folder structure and file names confer with the example in the documentation.

From a ***Getting Started*** page in some old documentation:

https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/wiki/GettingStarted

I found some info:

> After extracting the library . . . . . , you will have a new google-api-php-client-x.y directory. The library files themselves are in the google-api-php-client/src directory

So, you need to end up with a:

```
google-api-php-client
```

Directory, and a:

```
google-api-php-client/src
```

directory.

Quote:

> After obtaining the library  . .  , you will have a directory named google-api-php-client somewhere on your file system, containing the library files. Specifically, you will need to include the file src/Google_Client.php and src/contrib/Google_PlusService.php inside of your scripts.

The above quote is for ***Google_PlusService.php*** but that could be replace with whatever API service file you need to use.

There are multiple ways to include the needed library files into your code.

It seems that there was a change in naming conventions of files and folders that is explained in the documentation for migrating to a new library version.

https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/guide/migration

Before the Drive API can be used, authorization needs to take place.  The initial documentation I was looking at was for a ***command line*** application.  I don't want a command line application, I'm trying to build a web application.  So, server side authorization needs to be implemented first.

https://developers.google.com/drive/web/auth/web-server

The server side authorization needs an additional php file included into your code.

```
require_once "google-api-php-client/src/Google/Service/Oauth2.php";
```

The documentation is here:

https://developers.google.com/drive/web/auth/web-server